# A problem importing lightkurve python package

Tags: python, import, iterable, astropy

I am having a problem importing the lightkurve package due to an error within astropy.

I downloaded the lightkurve 2.4.0 package, and then ran the code "import lightkurve". The import did not succeed, what is the problem and how can it be fixed? Thanks!

This is the error message I am getting:

```
/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/bin/python /Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import lightkurve as lk
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightkurve/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from . import units  # enable ppt and ppm as units
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightkurve/units.py", line 2, in <module>
    from astropy import units as u
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/units/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import astrophys, cgs, misc, photometric, si
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/units/astrophys.py", line 9, in <module>
    from astropy.constants import si as _si
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/constants/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import cgs, si
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/constants/cgs.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .config import codata, iaudata
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/constants/config.py", line 14, in <module>
    codata = importlib.import_module(".constants." + phys_version, "astropy")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/constants/codata2018.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .constant import Constant, EMConstant
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/constants/constant.py", line 265, in <module>
    class EMConstant(Constant):
  File "/Users/yair1/PycharmProjects/TESSLC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/astropy/constants/constant.py", line 88, in __new__
    return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, d)
TypeError: 'ConstantMeta' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide an example of the code that causes the issue. the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the astropy version you are using?